# Python: Dedup a dictionary

Tags: python, scapy

Good afternoon,

I reading in a pcap and am basically trying to get a dedup'd list of BSSID's & ESSID's.  I am still getting duplicates with this code and cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong:

```
if not (t[0] in ssid_pairs and ssid_pairs[t[0]] == t[1]):
    ssid_pairs[t[0]] = t[1]
    of.write(t[0] + ',' + t[1] + ((',' + f + '\n') if verbose else '\n'))
```

ssid_pairs is a dictionary, t[0] is the bssid & t[1] is the essid.  An example of the dictionary is:

```
{'FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF':'MyWIFI',...}
```

I am still seeing multiple instances of the same key->value pair being written to the file.  I put some debugging print statements in and sometimes it will recognize a duplicate, sometimes it will not.  This is from a parse pcap with scapy.

Thanks for any help.

*** EDIT: Thanks everyone, I am not really solving my problem the right way with a dictionary.  Time to think this through a bit clearer...

Comment: Please add an example of the dictionary.

Comment: Note that dictionaries are already unique-valued in that each key is unique. 'De-duping' a dictionary doesn't make sense. Try it: `{'FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF':'MyWIFI', 'FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF':'MySecondWIFI'}` yields just `{'FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF':'MySecondWIFI'}`. If you want to dedup individual lists, that's a different matter altogether. Please clarify your question or provide your full code.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  Since i am parsing a pcap, I have a lot of packets with the same bssid / essid pair and I want to filter them out, but I do want to see the same bssid with a different essid (like a blank essid in the packet).

Comment: Oops, keep hitting enter for a line break and posting...  how can I keep these pairs together easily while dedup'ing the pairs?

Comment: You can use the bssd as keys and store a list of essids for each bssid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you get:

```
t[0] = 'foo'
t[1] = 'bar'
```

Then we hit your code above:

```
if not (t[0] in ssid_pairs and ssid_pairs[t[0]] == t[1]):
    ssid_pairs[t[0]] = t[1]
    of.write(t[0] + ',' + t[1] + ((',' + f + '\n') if verbose else '\n'))
```

The condition passes (because `t[0]` is not in `ssid_pairs`), so we set:

```
ssid_pairs[t[0]] = t[1]
```

Which gives us:

```
ssid_pairs = {
  'foo': 'bar',
}
```

In our next iteration of the loop, we read:

```
t[0] = 'foo'
t[1] = 'gizmo'
```

Your condition passes (because `ssid_pairs[t[0]] != t[1]`), so we set:

```
ssid_pairs[t[0]] = t[1]
```

Which gives us:

```
ssid_pairs = {
  'foo': 'gizmo',
}
```

Then we read the same data we encountered in our first iteration:

```
t[0] = 'foo'
t[1] = 'bar'
```

But because we just `ssid_pairs['foo'] = 'gizmo'`, your condition will pass again, and you  will once again write out the same data.

If you are trying to get a list of unique *pairs*, then maybe create a set of `(essid,bssid)` tuples:

```
seen_pairs = set()
...
if not ((t[0],t(1)) in seen_pairs):
    seen_pairs.add((t[0], t[1]))
    of.write(t[0] + ',' + t[1] + ((',' + f + '\n') if verbose else '\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries *can't* have duplicates:

```
some_data = [('foo', 'bar'),
             ('bang', 'quux'),
             ('foo', 'bar'),
             ('zappo', 'whoo'),
             ]

mydict = {}
for data in some_data:
    mydict[data[0]] = data[1]

import pprint; print(mydict)
```

The only way you're going to re-write the same data is if you aren't opening your file in `'w'` mode. But

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as of:
    for key in mydict:
        of.write('{},{}{}'.format(key, mydict[key], (',' + f + '\n') if verbose else '\n'))
```

Will never write the same line twice.